# Requesting size of Stream from consumer, before loading all the data

Tags: apache-camel

Hy all,
I have a problem with the camel component I am developing, where I'm not sure how to implement it in a way, that goes in line with the concepts of camel.

The producer I'm developing talks to the http api for our server, which is used to send messages with attachments.
Those attachments can potentially be very big, which is why the server expects the total filesize before any upload is done.

Currently the producer only accepts io.Files, nio.Paths and GenericFile, because there I can read the file size, before I upload the file.
Of course this is not a good way to do things, because it requires the (big) file to be available locally.
Connecting, for a example, a ftp server as the consumer would mean, that I have to download each file locally so I can upload it afterwards.

The obvious solution is using streams to access and upload the data, but with this I do not know how big the file is, before I'm done uploading, which is not an option, I need the size in advance.

My question now is, what are best practices to stream files through camel and also make the consumer give me the filesize in advance.

Greets
Chris

Answer (score 0):

For File/FTP consumer, the exchange in header has a key `CamelFileLength` (Exchange.FILE_LENGTH) which return the file size in remote ftp server from consumer's scan result.

Unlike the file size obtain from local, the file size in key `CamelFileLength` might differ from actual file size your application received

1. The ASCII mode will potentially change the linefeed when there is OS differ
2. The file size might change between consumer scan action and consumer pick actionn

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, this would result in two issues:

1. I can not rely on the CamelFileSize to be there at all
2. The file size in my application (which is the only one relevant to me) is basically wrong  

If so, this unfortunatelly does not help me with my problem =(

Comment: @Chris The CamelFileSize is reliable if you accept delay receive like using readlock or receive single file (exist in folder at least minutes) in each batch.

Comment: Well as long as the CamelFileSize is the correct value, when I have actually read the whole file, this is fine. But all this is only the case for the file component, isn't it? I can't rely on this header, when I receive a file from a different component, or am I wrong here?

Comment: @Chris The answer's point 2 also apply to file component. As state in above comment, the header `CamelFileSize` is reliable under restricted condition.